# Access control / parental control bridged routers

Tags: bridge

Does the access control / parental control work in a bridged router? I have the dsl modem that is also a router and is the main router and have the tp link 1043 as a bridge router and I am trying to set up the access control on it but it is not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your "bridged router" is *not* currently acting as a router. (That was the whole point of bridging it!) Packets going through a bridge bypass the IP layer, and therefore most likely bypass the parental control software as well.